# C# iTextSharp The color space is not supported

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am trying to extract some photos from a pdf file.  The biggest problem I am running into is that there are some images in the PDF file that iTextSharp (**Version 5.5.9.0**) doesn't seem to support.

> The color space [/Indexed, /DeviceCMYK, 13, 109 0 R] is not supported.

My question is, if itextsharp doesn't support extracting images with the above color space, is there any library that does?

[www.extractpdf.com](http://www.extractpdf.com) gets everything I need from this pdf file (though due to security reasons I cannot provide the pdf in question.)

I would use that website however I need to automate the extracting, replacing some colors, and putting images back into the pdf.  This part I have no trouble with, except there's a few images I cannot extract, convert, and place back into the pdf.

I've tried extract the images in question using a byte array but there doesn't seem to be any way to open the files regardless of what the file extension is.

```
var test = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader.GetStreamBytesRaw((iTextSharp.text.pdf.PRStream)PDFStremObj);

File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\pdf images\test\test" + i + ".jpg", test);
```

The "Mime" type for these "corrupt images" is application/octet-stream.  There are other images with this same mime type that seem to save properly with a .png extension.

If there is no other library that supports these types of images, then I suppose I will get back with the creator of this pdf file to see if they can convert a few images in the pdf and re-save it.

Comment: Please specify the iTextSharp version you are using (and if it is 7+, use the itext7 tag instead)

Comment: It's version 5.5.9.0